# AutoCompleteTextView для ArrayList собственного класса

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Создал на форме `AutoCompleteTextView` и передаю в него `ArrayList`, состоящий из элементов, созданного класса `Person`:

```
class Person {

    private String Name;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String firstName) {
        this.Name = firstName;
    }
}
```

`ArrayList` не пустой, элементы в нем есть, проверял.

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_message);
    ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Ошибок в коде нет, но во время тестирования и ввода текста, виджет не работает. Как сделать так, чтобы при наборе, виджет выдавал мне список элементов из `ArrayList`, соответствующих введенному тексту? (в классе только одно поле, по нему поиск и идет)

Answer (score 4):

Реализуйте метод toString() в своем классе-модели:

```
class Person {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return name;
    }
}
```

либо реализуйте собственный адаптер на основе стандартного, если требуется более сложный вывод.

PS: имена переменных и экземпляров классов в Java принято писать с маленькой буквы в [lowerCamelCase](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)-стиле. С Большой буквы пишутся имена классов

Comment: реализовал метод, но при тестировании приложения, при вводе слов в текстовое поле, выпадающий список не появляется